# Using Hovertool in Python with Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I am a new python learner and am trying to make a plot with bokeh. I want to use the hover tool and it is working when I scroll over the dots. However, the X and Y values are showing ??? instead of the actual values. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing incorrectly because the hovertool itself is working, but the values are not displaying.

```
    from bokeh.plotting import figure`
    from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook

    get_provider(Vendors.CARTODBPOSITRON)
    from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool  

    # Create a blank figure with labels
    p = figure(plot_width = 600, plot_height = 600, 
               title = 'Example Glyphs',
               x_axis_label = 'X', y_axis_label = 'Y')


    hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[
        ("X", "@X "),
        ("Y","@Y")])

    p = figure(x_axis_type="mercator", 
               y_axis_type="mercator",
               tools=[hover, 'wheel_zoom','save']) 

    p.add_tile(CARTODBPOSITRON)

    # Example data
    circles_x = [1, 3, 4, 5, 8]
    circles_y = [8, 7, 3, 1, 10]
    circles_x = [9, 12, 4, 3, 15]
    circles_y = [8, 4, 11, 6, 10]

    # Add squares glyph
    p.circle(squares_x, squares_y, size = 12, color = 'navy', alpha = 0.6)
    # Add circle glyph
    p.circle(circles_x, circles_y, size = 12, color = 'red')

    # Set to output the plot in the notebook
    output_notebook()
    # Show the plot
    show(p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't using an explicit `ColumnDataSource` (which would allow you to use and refer to whatever column names you want), then you must refer to the default column names Bokeh uses. In this case, for `circle`, the default column names are `"x"` and `"y"` (lower case, not upper case as you have above). So:

```py
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[
    ("X", "@x"),
    ("Y", "@y"),
])
```

Comment: You should update your question to be about the actual issue you are having.